# Not able to get the html data from Json using Jquery with Handlebars.js template

Tags: jquery, json, handlebars.js

I am having a json file, which has the json data like this :

```
{
    "username":"lgangula",
    "message":""
}
```

in the data.json file

i am getting the file, using jquery ajax method and appending the data using the Handlebars.js; here is the function:

```
var JsonHandler = function(url) {
        return $.getJSON(url)
};

(function ($) {

    var manupulate = function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key,value){
            if(key === "username"){
                            console.log(value) // i am getting the name
                var x = Handlebars.compile($("#header-template").html());
                console.log(x(value));//i am getting the elements, without the value..!?
            }
        })
    }


    var path = "js/data.json";
    new JsonHandler(path).done(function(data){
        manupulate(data);
    })

})(jQuery);
```

I am not getting the value in my html out put. here is the template i am use :

```
<script id="header-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="loginInfo"> <a href="#">{{username}}</a> | <a href="#">Logout</a> </div>
    </script>
```

what is going wrong here.. any one can help me please?

even i tried this way again:

```
(function ($) {

    var x = {"username":"lgangula"}


    var manupulate = function(data){
        $.each(x, function(key,value){
            if(key === "username"){
                console.log(value);//consoling the name
                var x = Handlebars.compile($("#header-template").html());
                console.log(x(value)); //no result here.
                            console.log(x({"username":"lgangula"})); //works fine
            }
        })
    }

    manupulate();

})(jQuery);
```

still not working..

in case if i pass the object like this, it works..

```
console.log(x({"username":"lgangula"})); //works fine
```

Comment: I tried the way you said, no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't render template try this,

```
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#header-template").html());
 var html =  template(x)
 console.log(html)
```

Comment: What is "x" here in your answer..? can you give further details please?

Comment: `var x = {"username":"lgangula"}`